# Meaning of curly Braces in Manpages

Tags: manpage

I looked here [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/man) (and on the german ubuntu-user wiki)  but couldnt find an answer.

 
I dont know what they mean e.g. in the manpage of `mpstat`:

```
SYNOPSIS
   mpstat [ -A ] [ -u ] [ -V ] [ -I { keyword [,...] | ALL } ] [ -P { cpu [,...] | ON | ALL } ] [ interval [ count ] ]
```

when they say `-I { keyword [,...] | ALL }` or `-P { cpu [,...] | ON | ALL }`

I would appreciate any clarification.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187946/ .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Command syntax is given in a form that is a bit like [Backus-Naur notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), described [here](http://linuxcommand.org/reading_man_pages.php).

The braces group together two or more options, one of which must be specified.
In the case of `-I { keyword [,...] | ALL }`, that means you either specify `keyword [,...]` *or* ALL.

Comment: What's meaning in the case `sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...`? from `man sed`

Answer (score 10):

Square braces `[...]` mean that their content is optional and can either be added to the command or not.

Curly brackets containing pipe-separated items `{ ... | ... }` mean that you must specify one of those items.

---

Example:

```
my_command [--optional-argument] { --either-this | --or-that }
```

Given the syntax above, you have those options to call the command:

```
my_command --either-this
my_command --or-that
my_command --optional-argument --either-this
my_command --optional-argument --or-that
```

Answer (score 2):

Taken from this [handy guide](http://www.tfug.org/helpdesk/general/man.html),

> Some options will have a limited list of choices. A list of choices will be comma seperated and put between braces.
>
> {choice1,choice2}
> {yes,no}

Where you have `-P { cpu [,...] | ON | ALL }`, it means you must choose one of the following options. The [,...] part means that you can supply a comma separated list.